# Training bias weight backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to write an `XOR` solution using neural networks and the `sigmoid` activation function. (With `True=0.9` and `False=0.1`)

I'm at the backpropagation part now.

The formula I was given for computing weight adjustments is:

```
delta_weight(l,i,j) = gamma*output(l,i)*error_signal(l,j)
```

i.e - the weight adjustment for the link between `layer 1 (hidden), node 2` and `layer 2(output), node 0` is:

```
delta_weight(1,2,0)
```

I chose `gamma=0.5`

Since bias weights are associated with a single node I guessed the weight adjustment formula was:

```
delta_weight(l,i) = gamma*output(l,i)
```

My program is not working, clearly my guess was incorrect. Could someone help me along?

Thanks a bunch!

**EDIT: CODE**

```
def applyInputs(self, inps):

    for i in range(len(self.layers)-1):
        for n, node in enumerate(self.layers[i+1].nodes):

            ans = 0         

            for m, mode in enumerate(self.layers[i].nodes):
                ans += self.links[stringify(i,m,i+1,n)].weight * mode.output

            if node.bias == True:
                ans+= self.links[stringify(-1,-1,i+1,n)].weight

            node.set_output(response(ans))

    return self.layers[len(self.layers)-1].nodes[0].output



def computeErrorSignals(self, out): # 'out' is the output of the entire network (only 1 output node)

    # output node error signal

    output_node = self.layers[len(self.layers)-1].nodes[0]
    fin_err = (out - output_node.output)*output_node.output*(1-output_node.output)  
    output_node.set_error(fin_err)

    # hidden node error signals

    for j in range(len(self.layers[1].nodes)):

        hid_node = self.layers[1].nodes[j]
        err = (hid_node.output)*(1-hid_node.output)*self.layers[2].nodes[0].error_signal*self.links[stringify(1,j,2,0)].weight          
        hid_node.set_error(err)


def computeWeightAdjustments(self):

    for i in range(len(self.layers)-1):
        for n, node in enumerate(self.layers[i+1].nodes):
            for m, mode in enumerate(self.layers[i].nodes):                                     
                self.links[stringify(i,m,i+1,n)].weight += ((0.5)*self.layers[i+1].nodes[n].error_signal*self.layers[i].nodes[m].output)

            if node.bias == True:
                self.links[stringify(-1,-1,i+1,n)].weight += ((0.5)*self.layers[i].nodes[m].output)
```

Comment: Can you post The entire code ?

Comment: Gamma stands to learning rate ?

Comment: yes gamma is the learning rate... do you want the entire code... ¬200 lines, or just the backpropogation?

Comment: Part of it basically The update process with back propagation would be nice

Comment: Maybe you are not missing only one thing.

Comment: I've posted some of the code - The functions (in running order), applying the input pattern, computing the error signals, and adjusting the weights. As you can see I used `gamma=0.5`. The notation is different, if you've any questions please ask